# Degrees of freedom in the smoothing spline fit in a GAM formula

Tags: r, spline, smoothing, gam, cubic-spline

If the smoothing spline is simply a natural cubic spline with knots at every unique value of `x_i`. Then why does `gam::s()` in R need a degree of freedom?

Answer (score 2):

Because it is smoothing not interpolation. The degree of freedom tells how much complexity you want in the fitted spline.